# Is it safe to Mix different mortars together

Tags: ceramic-tile

Is it safe to mix ultraflex lft and a rapid setting mortar together?
I'm short on funds and I have a 50lb bag of ultraflex LFT but I need more to finish the job. I have a half a bag of Ultraflex rapid setting morter. Would it be okay to mix these?

Comment: Why mix them?  Why not just use the one up and then use the other?  Or do you really mean "Is it OK to switch between mortars on the same job?"

Comment: I was meaning as in mixing them together in the same bucket,

Comment: Then no, I see no reason to mix them together in the same bucket.  Just use one up til it's gone, and then use the other.

Answer (score 3):

It might work fine, but you might find that the setting time is short or shorter than expected.

I would consider using one then the other. Perhaps setting up and using the quicker hardening one in small batches.

Comment: ‘Might work’ suggests a chance of epic failure. There’s no reason in the universe to take that chance.